# how to access odata from http request

Tags: node.js, axios, xmlhttprequest, odata

Hello I'm using axios for my get request and I am able to get a response from the request, however I want to get access to odata within the object that is returned.

here is the returned object from res.data

```
{
  '@odata.context': 'https://ddf.house.com/odata/v1/$metadata#Property(ListingKey)',
  value: [
    {
      ListingKey: '20586562',
      
    },
    {
      ListingKey: '22792237',
     
    }
  ],
  '@odata.nextLink': "https://ddf.house.ca/odata/v1/Property?$top=2&$skip=2&$select=ListingKey"
}
```

I'm trying to access the @odata.nextLink property.

So to access the value I just use

```
.then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.value);
        })
```

But how do I access odata.nextLink? using the dot notation won't allow me to use something like this.

```
res.data.@odata.nextLink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an array item  by [] operator

Using this code

```
res.data["@odata.context"]
```

Demo - running local own REST API server, call it by axios then access `@odata.nextLink`

```
const axios = require("axios");

axios.get("http://localhost:3001/users")
    .then(res => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data, null, 4))
        console.log('-------------------------------------')
        console.log(res.data["@odata.context"])
    })
```

result

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://ddf.house.com/odata/v1/$metadata#Property(ListingKey)",
    "value": [
        {
            "ListingKey": "20586562"
        },
        {
            "ListingKey": "22792237"
        }
    ],
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://ddf.house.ca/odata/v1/Property?$top=2&$skip=2&$select=ListingKey"
}
-------------------------------------
https://ddf.house.com/odata/v1/$metadata#Property(ListingKey)
```

[image]